# Http requests silently fail when using ionic view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that can't login or log with ionic pro monitoring when attempting to use with Ionic View. I've tried using alerts to get more information but that had limited results.
[image: Response from logging in]

Comment: can you please put http request code sample?

Comment: Try Reinstalling cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Comment: whitelist plugin didn't help